# Javascript button mousenter

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is wrong with this code? The button doesn't work after hovering it.
The code is just copied from the instructional website and it works there.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button Magic</title>

        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
      </script>     

    </head>
    <body>
     <div><br/><strong>Click Me!</strong></div>   
    </body>
</html>

div {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #69D2E7;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").mouseenter(function() {
        $("div").fadeTo("fast", 1)
    });

   $("div").mouseleave(function() {
    $("div").fadeTo("fast", 0.1)

});

});
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see a button anywhere.

Comment: What's it supposed to do? It fades in and out as you mouse over. What else did you expect it to do? And I assume your "instructional" website is: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-bay3D/2/5

Comment: Also note: You code as posted doesn't actually load the jquery library.

Answer (score 1):

Possible advise #1: *You don't want to fade it away that much.*

Change the value of `fadeTo()` to .5 as this was the initial value in your css.

---

Possible advise #2: *It doesn't do anything when you click on it.*

Add an `onclick="alert('Clicked!');"` to the div container.

---

Possible advise #3: *You just want an hover effect for html element.*

Why not use just CSS 3 transition:

```
 div {
   transition: opacity 1s;
   opacity: .5;
 }

 div:hover {
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

Notice: Of course you'll can use vendor-prefixes to support more browsers, like `-webkit-transition`.